# Select with table join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get * from concrete_samples but only method_name and not the id from concrete_compaction_methods

```
SELECT * FROM concrete_samples,concrete_compaction_methods WHERE concrete_compaction_methods.id = concrete_samples.compaction_method AND workorder_id=1
```

This is currently returning everything I want EXCEPT it's giving me the id column of the methods table which I don't want.

the pseudo code of the statement I want to do is

```
SELECT * FROM concrete_samples,  SELECT method_name FROM concrete_compaction_methods WHERE concrete_compaction_methods.id = concrete_samples.compaction_method AND workorder_id=1
```

I've done some research. I've tried to use a union but i don't think that's the correct or neatest solution

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advise:

- Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases in your query.
- Qualify all column references.

So the query looks more like this:

```
SELECT cs.*, ccm.method_name
FROM concrete_samples cs JOIN
     concrete_compaction_methods ccm
     ON ccm.id = cs.compaction_method 
WHERE cs.workorder_id = 1;
```

I am guessing that `workorder_id` comes from `concrete_samples` rather than the other table.

Comment: Thank, I will test this out.

Comment: I have another table to join and have modified the query like this, is it still the "correct" way as i want to use best practises

` SELECT cs.*, ccm.method_name, csm.method_name
 FROM concrete_samples cs 
 JOIN
     concrete_compaction_methods ccm
  ON ccm.id = cs.compaction_method
 JOIN
  concrete_sampling_methods csm
  on csm.id = cs.sampling_method
 WHERE cs.workorder_id = $1;
`

Answer (score 1):

Try below -

```
SELECT concrete_samples.*,method_name 
   FROM concrete_samples inner join concrete_compaction_methods 
   on concrete_compaction_methods.id = concrete_samples.compaction_method 
where workorder_id=1
```

Comment: Works perfectly I thought it would be something similar but just couldn't wrap my head around it... Thank you for the knowledge